# I want to query post based on post object sub field but not the post_id

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type, wordpress-rest-api

I have 2 acf custom post type

1. target_crop
2. product

Plugins that I am using: Custom Post Type UI, Advanced Custom Fields and ACF to REST API

target_crop: There is one field call target_crop(text)

product: There are 3 fields product_name(text), technical_composition(text), target_crop(post_object->ref to target_crop)

When I hit {{url}}/target_crop I get this below response from the ACF to Rest API which is fine.

[image]

And when I hit {{url}}/product I get this below response

[image]

Now what I want is I want to add a filter like {{url}}product?**target_crop=Rice** so it will only show the data for that target_crop.

I have tried adding meta query

```
if(isset($_GET['target_crop']) && !empty($_GET['target_crop'])){
  $meta_query['meta_query'][] = [
    'key' => 'target_crop',
    'value' => $_GET['target_crop'],
    'compare' => 'LIKE'
  ];
}
```

But it is not showing anything at all.

On the other hand instead of {{url}}product?**target_crop=Rice** if I add {{url}}product?**target_crop=70** 70 which is the id for rice then it showing perfectly fine.

I want to query post based on post object sub field but not the id.